# Information about requests made from client browser?

Tags: javascript, http

Is there a way to detect which HTTP requests (from client Javascript) are sent with a successful status, when client visits my page? Or just check if specific part (lines of code) of third-party Javascript code is sending HTTP GET request with successful status?
It is possible with, for example, a Chrome extension, but can that be done in client side Javascript?

EDIT:
Please note, that I am new to web related stuff and have done a research on whether it is or in not possible, but that yielded no results. Therefore I am asking this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that can't be done with JavaScript.

JS doesn't have access to network traffic like that for a good reason:

### Security

If that were possible, any site could get access to whatever you're sending to and receiving from your bank, for example.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :-) Does it also answer your question?